# How to check if an element of matrices is even or not in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a problem as follows -

> Script: Using ’If’ condition inside a ’for’ loop
>
> - Create a new script and save it using your name and matric ID.
> - Use ’for’ loop to create two matrices `A` and `B`. The size of the matrices are same, and the matrices are of 5 by 4 size.
> - Each element of the matrix `A` will be determined in the ’for’ loop using the following formula `A(i,j) = a*i +b*j`;  where `a` and `b` are
>   the last two digits of your matric ID (here `a = 2` and `b = 5`).
>   `i` and `j` are the row number and column number of the matrices respectively.
> - The elements of the matrix `B` will be changed from 0 to 1 ’if’ the corresponding element of the matrix `A` is even number.

I tried to solve in this way but it won't work. What is the correct way to check if an element is even or not in MATLAB matrices?

```
clc
% clear all
A = zeros(5,4);
B =  zeros(5,4);
for j = 1:5
    for i = 1:4
        A(i,j) = 2*i + 5 * j;
        if mod(B(i,j),2) == 0
            A(i,j) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines in your code

```
        if mod(B(i,j),2) == 0
            A(i,j) = 1;
        end
```

set `A(i,j)` to `1` if `mod(B(i,j)) == 0`. This is always `true` since you have initialized `B` with zeros. You shloud do it the other way around, test if `mod(A(i,j),2) == 0` and set `B(i,j) = 1`